# SQL Server - Aggregate by most rows with value

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Given a table,

```
id     name
1      Joe
2      Bob
3      Joe
4      Joe
5      Bob
```

I would like to do an aggregate selection, returning the 'name' with the highest number of rows.

To illustrate, there are 3 'Joe's above, and only 2 'Bob's. Therefore, I would like to return 'Joe'.

I don't believe there is an aggregate function in SQL Server dedicated to doing this. `count` and `max` wouldn't do the job.

#### UPDATE

I suppose I could say:

```
 select max(names) as winning_name
   from (
         select name, 
                count(*) as names 
           from ultimate_table 
          group by name
        ) as grp
```

But is there a better way to do this without a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this would sort things by frequency:

```
SELECT name FROM name_table ORDER BY count(1) DESC
```

Then you simply limit the results to 1 row, depending on SQL flavour:

```
SELECT name FROM name_table ORDER BY count(1) DESC LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM name_table ORDER BY count(1) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from name_table
group by name
having count(*)= (select max(names)
   from (
         select 
                count(*) as names 
           from name_table 
          group by name
        ) as grp
)
```

You will have to use subquery if more than one name has maximumn number of occurrences.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b7be/14)

```
create table name_table(id int,name varchar(10));
insert into name_table values(1,'Joe');
insert into name_table values(2,'Bob');
insert into name_table values(3,'Joe');
insert into name_table values(4,'Joe');
insert into name_table values(5,'Batman');
insert into name_table values(6,'Batman');
insert into name_table values(7,'Batman');
```

**Output**

```
NAME
----
Batman
Joe
```

Comment: This method works if you want all names with the same maximum count, possible > 1 result.

Comment: Didn't my offered query in my question do the exist same thing in less code?